# Firebird - Select com data menor que 10 dias

Tags: sql, firebird

Pesquisei mas não entendi como usar a função [DATEDIFF()](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-datediff.html) no *FIREBIRD* o que eu preciso é que a consulta me retorne registros com datas até 10 dias anteriores a partir da data **atual**.

**Obs:** Entenda data atual pelo dia em que a consulta for feita.

Vou colocar um exemplo que funcionaria no *mysql* onde tenho melhor dominio, mas o que eu preciso é um exemplo de como ficaria em **FIREBIRD**.

```
select 
pag_id as ID,
pag_data_emissao as EMISSAO,
pag_valor AS VALOR,
pag_historico AS HISTORICO,
pag_saldo AS SALDO, 
pag_debito_credito as deb_cred
from tab_banco_lanc where pag_data_emissao >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função DATEDIFF do Firebird retorna a diferença entre uma data e outra, de acordo com o primeiro parâmetro da função, que podem ser:

- `day` : diferença em dias;
- `month` : diferença em meses;
- `year` : diferença em anos.

Sintaxe:

```
DATEDIFF( <YEAR | MONTH | DAY>, DATA_1, DATA_2 )
```

Fica assim, a resposta para a sua questão:

```
SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTO WHERE datediff(day, :DATA, DATAHORA_INICIO) < 10;
```

Compare o resultado do DATEDIFF com o numero de dias que você deseja. Neste caso irá retornar todos os documentos da tabela onde a diferença em dias entre a DATAHORA_INICIO, e a data do parâmetro, :DATA, for menor que 10;

Comment: Obrigado, consegui testar com a sua resposta, tive só que mudar os parametros e nome da tabela, mas rodou certinho !

Comment: Ah sim.. esqueci de mudar o exemplo de acordo com a sua tabela!

Comment: Estou com um problema parecido http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120596/como-fazer-um-sql-que-consulte-apenas-o-dia-de-uma-data

Answer (score 0):

Consegui usando o **DATEADD** e negativando o parametro, achei mais simples:

```
select
    CONTROLE as ID,
    DATA as EMISSAO,
    VALOR AS VALOR,
    HISTORICO AS HISTORICO,
    SALDO AS SALDO,
    DEBITOCREDITO as deb_cred
from BTR06
where DATA >= DATEADD( - 5 DAY TO CURRENT_DATE ) and CODIGO=7
```